# How do I make this typescript function return strong typed array instead of string[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function that I'm trying to convert from js to ts, I thought that the type of the variable `hi` will be `('s'|'bb')[]` but actually it's `string[]`. How can I get typescript to infer K to be the keys of NewOptions?

```
export const getWithOverrides = <
  K extends string,
  NewOptions extends { [x in K]?: boolean },
  Overrides extends { [x in K]?: boolean }
>(
  newOptions: NewOptions,
  overrides: Overrides
): K[] =>
  (Object.keys(newOptions) as K[]).filter(key => {
    if (typeof overrides[key] === 'boolean') {
      return overrides[key];
    }
    return newOptions[key];
  });

const hi = getWithOverrides({ s: true, bb: true }, { s: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by removing the `K` type parameter, requiring that the object types extend `Record<string, boolean>`, and using `keyof` with your two object types:

```typescript
export const getWithOverrides = <
    NewOptions extends Record<string, boolean>,
    Overrides extends Record<string, boolean>
>(
    newOptions: NewOptions,
    overrides: Overrides
): (keyof NewOptions | keyof Overrides)[] =>
    Object.keys(newOptions).filter((key) => {
        if (typeof overrides[key] === "boolean") {
            return overrides[key];
        }
        return newOptions[key];
    });

const hi = getWithOverrides({ s: true, bb: true }, { s: true });
//    ^? const hi: ("s" | "bb")[]
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgdQJYwAWA8gG7BRR4AmwqcAvHADwBQcHcAcsAO7FgYeFPVAxgyavQBKwJFGrN0VZBgA0cAEYQIAG2ABDZAD417TmQpVaokOMky50RcryqN2vYZOtjACnMOZD4BIREALm4QwWE0M044CHJKGjpIyxSbVgBKSL8Aa2AATwgAMyj+GJE4AB84QpLyjOs6bIBtAF1GY0C4Yk0AKzkYADoG1D9gyrC0bJHSvF1xKD8C4uzuuABvXoS8cr8YIrBgMsTkltQ2hq6GO7gAIk99IweNnYTPzihsAFcoZDnKypK43ADcu04AF9IRwfjB-oCpqFYqDih0IQkodkIawkGh4IQ8Iw4FhcAQSBcQX4tnBUJEYFBfsAPJoGUzgHAoRpafS4IzmVycawAPQihIAPQA-EA)